# Problems with virtualhost and alias Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to use a virtualhost with an alias to deploy a Laravel application.
Using apache2 in ubuntu 16.04.

My 000.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    Alias /expediente "/var/www/public/"

    <Directory /var/www/public/>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

The first one is working ok but the second one does not.

What am I doing wrong?

==============

### EDIT

Ok so i made two conf files in sites available and symlinked them to sites-enabled.

advanced.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName ip-address:80/advanced
    ServerAlias /advanced
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/advanced
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

expediente.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName ip-address:80/expediente
    ServerAlias /expediente
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Reloaded and restarted apache2.

If i try to navigate to ip-address/ i get the first page, the advanced,
If i try to navigate to ip-address/advanced 404 not found
If i try to navigate to ip-address/expediente 404 not found

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its good practice create different host file for your alias. you can use this command to copy default config for your second alias with this command

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

and open it in whichever editor you like and put this content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

save and close the file then run this command
`sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`
and restart your apache

Comment: Ok so i made two conf files, one for the app that is running already, and the other one to host my Laravel app. I named them advanced.conf and expediente.conf. Also i did the a2ensite thing for each one. Each one has a ServerName ipaddress:80/advanced and ipaddress:80/expediente, which the respective DocumentRoot and ServerAlias (/advanced and /expediente), if i access the server with only the ipadress:80/ the first page works. If i try to access ipadress:80/expediente or ipadress:80/advanced it throws a 404 not found... what could it be? am i missing something?

Comment: use `advanced` and `expediente` as ServerAlias, don't put /

Comment: and use only alias in browser (you don't have to use your ip address).
If it shows `This site can’t be reached`, just edit /etc/host file and add `127.0.0.1 yourAlias` at the end of file

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need ServerName in your virtual hosts configurations, its probably always defaulting to the first one without that. For example

ServerName mydomain.net

Answer (score -1):

Si tus proyecto esta de la forma http://localhost/AppName, entonces debes colocar en el httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost site1.local:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
         DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/site1
         ServerName www.site1.local
         ServerAlias site1.com 
     </VirtualHost>
```

y el segundo.

```
<VirtualHost site2.local:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/site2
     ServerName www.site2.local
     ServerAlias site2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Y si lo quiero hacer solo con IP?, así como lo muestro en la edición que hice de la pregunta. No quiero que tenga dominio ya que serán temporales.